# Getting a Request Token using php in Flickr: oauth_problem=signature_invalid

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, flickr, hmacsha1

### Origin question

I want to upload photos to Flickr by using PHP, and first I need to do the User Authentication with OAuth.

Here is the reference of the [api doc](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html):

> First, you must create a base string from your request. The base string is constructed by concatenating the HTTP verb, the request URL, and all request parameters sorted by name, using lexicograhpical byte value ordering, separated by an '&'.
>
> Use the base string as the text and the key is the concatenated values of the Consumer Secret and Token Secret, separated by an '&'.

And according to [this](https://www.flickr.com/groups/51035612836@N01/discuss/72157664394852218/72157668249952899), `tokenSecret` is an empty string when calling `request_token`

Here is my code snippet:

```php
/**
 * generateSignature
 * @param        $httpVerb
 * @param        $requestUrl
 * @param        $parameters
 * @param string $tokenSecret
 *
 * @return string
 */
function generateSignature($httpVerb, $requestUrl, $parameters, $tokenSecret=''){
    global $consumerSecret;
    ksort($parameters);
    $queryStr = http_build_query($parameters);
    //not urlencode, same error
    //$baseStr = $httpVerb . '&' . $requestUrl . '&' . $queryStr;
    //urlencode
    $baseStr = urlencode($httpVerb . '&' . $requestUrl . '&' . $queryStr);
    $key = $consumerSecret . '&' . $tokenSecret;
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $baseStr, $key, false);
    return $signature;
}

/**
 * getRequestToken
 * @return string
 */
function getRequestToken(){
    global $consumerKey;
    global $callbackUrl;
    $requestTokenURL = 'https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token';
    $queryParameters = [
        //nonce: temporarily use hard code
        'oauth_nonce' => '83273423',
        'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_version' => '1.0',
        'oauth_callback' => urlencode($callbackUrl),
    ];
    $queryParameters['oauth_signature'] = generateSignature('GET', $requestTokenURL, $queryParameters);
    $queryStr = http_build_query($queryParameters);
    return $requestTokenURL . '?' . $queryStr;
}

$consumerKey = '<YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY>';
$consumerSecret = '<YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET>';
$callbackUrl = '<YOUR_REDIRECT_URL>';
$requestTokenURLWithQueryStr = getRequestToken();
// echo $requestTokenURLWithQueryStr;exit;
header('Location: '. $requestTokenURLWithQueryStr);
```

But I got "oauth_problem=signature_invalid" from Flickr, I don't know where am I wrong, anyone who familiar with this can help me out?

---

### Update

Well first I must thank @CBroe for pointing out my wrong point, and here is my code after modified:

```
/**
 * generateSignature
 * @param        $httpVerb
 * @param        $requestUrl
 * @param        $parameters
 * @param string $tokenSecret
 *
 * @return string
 */
function generateSignature($httpVerb, $requestUrl, $parameters, $tokenSecret=''){
    global $consumerSecret;
    ksort($parameters);
    $queryStr = http_build_query($parameters);
    $queryStr = urlencode(urldecode($queryStr));
    // echo $queryStr;exit;
    $baseStr = $httpVerb . '&' . urlencode($requestUrl) . '&' . $queryStr;
    echo $baseStr;exit;
    $key = $consumerSecret;
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $baseStr, $key, false);
    return $signature;
}

/**
 * getRequestToken
 * @return string
 */
function getRequestToken(){
    global $oauth_nonce;
    global $oauth_timestamp;
    global $oauth_consumer_key;
    global $oauth_callback;
    $requestTokenURL = 'https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token';
    $queryParameters = [
        'oauth_nonce' => $oauth_nonce,
        'oauth_timestamp' => $oauth_timestamp,
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $oauth_consumer_key,
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_version' => '1.0',
        'oauth_callback' => urlencode($oauth_callback),
    ];
    // var_dump($queryParameters);exit;
    $queryParameters['oauth_signature'] = generateSignature('GET', $requestTokenURL, $queryParameters);
    $queryStr = http_build_query($queryParameters);
    return $requestTokenURL . '?' . $queryStr;
}

$oauth_nonce = '95613465';
$oauth_timestamp = '1305586162';
$oauth_consumer_key = '653e7a6ecc1d528c516cc8f92cf98611';
$oauth_consumer_secret = '*******';
$oauth_callback = 'http://www.example.com';

$requestTokenURLWithQueryStr = getRequestToken();
header('Location: '. $requestTokenURLWithQueryStr);
```

I'm now using exactly the same parameter as [the example](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html), and I must point out one thing, in the example, the `oauth_nonce` and the `oauth_timestamp` parameter in the “URL” is not the same as their in the “base string”(see screenshot below):
[image]

I'm using the `oauth_nonce` and the `oauth_timestamp` parameter in the "base string" so that I can generate exactly the same "base string" as the example.

Run my code and this `echo $baseStr;exit;` statement will print the "base string", it's exactly the same as the one in the example right?

But, even I reproduce the example, if I replace the parameters's (`$oauth_nonce`,`$oauth_timestamp`,`$oauth_consumer_key`,`$oauth_consumer_secret`,`$oauth_callback`) value to my own, same error "signature_invalid". What should I do now?

---

### Update 2

Here is my code that updated(of course I had replace the parameters to my owns, especially `oauth_consumer_key` and `oauth_consumer_secret` and `oauth_callback`), but still return signature invalid:

```php
function generateSignature($httpVerb, $requestUrl, $parameters, $tokenSecret=''){
    global $consumerSecret;
    ksort($parameters);
    $queryStr = http_build_query($parameters);
    $queryStr = urlencode($queryStr);
    $baseStr = $httpVerb . '&' . urlencode($requestUrl) . '&' . $queryStr;
    $key = $consumerSecret . '&' . $tokenSecret;
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $baseStr, $key, false);
    return $signature;
}

function getRequestToken(){
    global $oauth_nonce;
    global $oauth_timestamp;
    global $oauth_consumer_key;
    global $oauth_callback;
    $requestTokenURL = 'https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token';
    $queryParameters = [
        'oauth_nonce' => $oauth_nonce,
        'oauth_timestamp' => $oauth_timestamp,
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $oauth_consumer_key,
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_version' => '1.0',
        'oauth_callback' => $oauth_callback,
    ];
    // var_dump($queryParameters);exit;
    $queryParameters['oauth_signature'] = generateSignature('GET', $requestTokenURL, $queryParameters);
    $queryStr = http_build_query($queryParameters);
    return $requestTokenURL . '?' . $queryStr;
}

//official document example paramters
$oauth_nonce = '95613465';
$oauth_timestamp = '1305586162';
$oauth_consumer_key = '653e7a6ecc1d528c516cc8f92cf98611';
$oauth_consumer_secret = '*******';
$oauth_callback = 'http://www.example.com';

$requestTokenURLWithQueryStr = getRequestToken();
// echo $requestTokenURLWithQueryStr;exit;
header('Location: '. $requestTokenURLWithQueryStr);
```

### Update 3(Finally I solve this issue, thanks to [[PHP] Flickr OAuth PHP 認證小筆記 Part 2](https://blog.hinablue.me/php-note-flickr-oauth-note-part-2/amp/))

Save the following code to a php file(say `test.php`), than replace the `oauth_consumer_key`, `oauth_consumer_secert` and `oauth_callback` parameter to yours, and run the code, you will succeed(and please don't believe the [official api](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html), it's totally a bullshit):

```php
<?php
/**
 * generateSignature
 * @param        $httpVerb
 * @param        $requestUrl
 * @param        $parameters
 * @param string $tokenSecret
 *
 * @return string
 */
function generateSignature($httpVerb, $requestUrl, $parameters, $tokenSecret=''){
    global $oauth_consumer_secret;
    ksort($parameters);
    $queryStr = http_build_query($parameters);
    $baseStr = $httpVerb . '&' . urlencode($requestUrl) . '&' . urlencode($queryStr);
    $key = $oauth_consumer_secret . '&' . $tokenSecret;
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $baseStr, $key, true);
    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));
    return $signature;
}

/**
 * Get authorization header
 * @return array
 */
function getRequestHeaders(){
    global $oauth_consumer_key;
    global $oauth_callback;
    global $requestTokenURL;
    $queryParameters = [
        'oauth_nonce' => crc32(time()),
        'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $oauth_consumer_key,
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_version' => '1.0',
        'oauth_callback' => $oauth_callback,
    ];
    // var_dump($queryParameters);exit;
    $queryParameters['oauth_signature'] = generateSignature('GET', $requestTokenURL, $queryParameters);
    
    //urldecode the oauth_callback url(cause http_build_query() will urlencode it)
    $queryStr = urldecode(http_build_query($queryParameters));
    
    //replace "&" with ","，and add double quote at the right side of the "=" and the left side of the ","，
    //doing this is because we need to add double quote to the value of the query string, because this string
    //will use as authorization header, not as query string.
    $authorization = str_replace('&', '", ', str_replace('=', '="', $queryStr)) . '"';
    $authorization = 'Authorization: OAuth realm="", ' . $authorization;
    return [$authorization];
}

/**
 * getRequestToken
 * @return array
 */
function getRequestToken(){
    $headers = getRequestHeaders();
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    //in case you need a proxy
    //curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'http://127.0.0.1:1087');
    $returnStr = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    $returnArr = [];
    parse_str($returnStr, $returnArr);
    return $returnArr;
}

$requestTokenURL = 'https://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token';

$oauth_consumer_key = '<YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY>';
$oauth_consumer_secret = '<YOUR_CONSUMER_SECERT>';
$oauth_callback = '<YOUR_CALLBACK_URL>';

$tokens = getRequestToken();
var_dump($tokens);
```

It turn out that we need to pass the parameter in the http header and the [official api](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html) never say any thing about it, this make me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $baseStr = urlencode($httpVerb . '&' . $requestUrl . '&' . $queryStr);
> ```

Doesn’t look like you are supposed to URL-encode the whole thing here.

The example in their docs says, you should get a string value like

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2F…
```

Yours however, because of the URL encoding applied in the above place, is

```
GET%26https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2F…
```

at that point already.

You need to URL-encode the parts separately here, and then join them together with a simple `&` afterwards.

(Not sure if the `$queryStr` needs an *extra* level of encoding here, `http_build_query` should have already taken care of properly encoding the parameters and values inside it. But `$requestUrl` does in any case.)

Comment: Actually I've tried not url-encode "the whole thing", but it response the same error "signature_invalid"

Comment: Did you encode the $requestUrl at least? That definitively needs encoding, that should be clear with one look at the example they provide. And as I said, not sure about the query string, whether that might or might not need a second level of encoding, when placed into this final string.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for reminding, I'm now modified my code and updated my question, but still not working, could you take a look at my code and see where am I wrong?

Comment: `urlencode(urldecode())` doesn’t have much point to begin with. What happens if you leave that value as-is (`http_build_query` has applied one level of URL-encoding already), and encode only the $requestUrl?

Comment: (And `echo $baseStr;exit;` isn’t really in there, you’re calculating and returning the signature actually, yes?)

Comment: Actually `urlencode(urldecode())` will do something, because the `http_build_query` will urlencode the `oauth_callback` parameter, I need to decode it, and then encode the entire thing again(this will tranform `=` to `%3D` `/` to `%2F` and `:` to `%3A`), if you have run my code, you will got the "base string" exactly the same as the one in the example, and I think that means my code is correct. `echo $baseStr;exit;` is in there, I had update my question, `echo $baseStr;exit;` is in the **update** part, please scroll down the page.

Comment: _“Actually urlencode(urldecode()) will do something”_ - no it won’t, these operations completely reverse each other. (Yes, it _does_ something, in the same way `x + 5 - 5` would - some operations are performed, but the _end result_ will still be the same as x was to begin with.) _“because the http_build_query will urlencode the oauth_callback parameter”_ - it encodes _all_ of them, as it _should_ - but you added a second level of encoding for that parameter specifically, by placing it in the parameter array as `'oauth_callback' => urlencode($oauth_callback)`, so remove that _there_.

Comment: _“echo $baseStr;exit; is in the update part”_ - yes, I realize that, but you said it was “still not working”, and when you _exit_ the function before you actually calculated and returned the signature, that would only to be expected. It was not clear whether that was supposed to be a temporary debug measure, or an oversight.

Comment: I encode the callback url `'oauth_callback' => urlencode($oauth_callback),` because this parameter encoded in the doc example `&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com`

Comment: I'm now change `'oauth_callback' => urlencode($oauth_callback),` to `'oauth_callback' => $oauth_callback,` and change `$queryStr = urlencode(urldecode($queryStr));` to `$queryStr = urlencode($queryStr);` and the result is, the `$baseStr` is the same as the one in the doc example if I use the same parameter as it in the doc.

Comment: I update my code again, in part `Update 2`, can you take a look? thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211150/discussion-between-bruce-xie-and-cbroe).